# Export Xcode comments generated documentation

Tags: swift, xcode

Is there any way to export the created documentation in Xcode project without library. To export it in the same kind as the apple swift documentation.

Comment: What do you mean by 'export'? Like, providing a documentation for your custom-written functions so that you can know about them during option-click?

Comment: I have this functionality, I mean to generate file or a way to open all of this functions at the apple ones https://imgur.com/a/1ZZZMwK

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. The command line tool is `xcodebuild docbuild`. You can find the official documentation at [Distributing Documentation to External Developers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/distributing-documentation-to-external-developers).